# Maatwebsite Call to a member function all() on array

Tags: maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to generate/download the excel from the table but an errors  keeps showing `Call to a member function all() on array`

Note: I've removed the constructor in here

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;


class VehicleRequestExportDestination implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;

    public function collection() 
    {
        $this->dateFrom = $this->dateFrom . ' 00:00:00.000';
        $this->dateTo   = $this->dateTo . ' 23:59:59.999';

        $query = "
        SELECT 
            SUBSTRING(destination,LOCATE('|',destination),LENGTH(destination)) AS dest,
            COUNT(destination) AS total 
        FROM dispatches
        WHERE
            addedDate
        BETWEEN 
            '" . $this->dateFrom . "' AND '" . $this->dateTo . "' 
        GROUP BY 
            destination 
        ORDER BY 
            total DESC
        LIMIT 10";

        return DB::select($query);
    }
}
```

This is how I call it from my controller

`return (new VehicleRequestExportDestination("2000-05-05","2030-05-05"))->download('Frequent Destination.xlsx');`

What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have a missing function. I also need it to convert to collection. This function solved my problem.

`return collect(DB::select($query));`

Instead of just returning

`return DB::select($query);`